# How do I execute a callback in angular-ui $modal *before* the modal closes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

angular-ui `$modal` supports promises for window closed or dismissed using `modalInstance.result.then(closeFn,dismissFn)`.

So if I am using a modal to gather information for a new Item, then I can do:

```
        modalInstance.result.then(function (item) {
          new Item(item).$save(); // or similar
        }, function () {
        });
```

And html snippet:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close(item)">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$dismiss()">Cancel</button>
```

But the new item might have a conflict, or it might be invalid on the server-side, or lots of other things. Is there any way I can catch this *before* the modal itself is closed? I would like to catch the "Yes" (or "Close") click, run my fn that does `new Item(item).$save()`, and then:

- if that succeeds, continue to close the modal
- if it fails, highlight with error messages

I know I could use a different `ng-click` on the button, and catch it in the `$modal` controller like such:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save(item)">Save</button>
```

And the code:

```
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: '/partials/createItem.html',
          controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.save = function(item) {
                        new Item(item).$save().then(function(){
                            modalInstance.close();
                        });
                    };

          }
        });
```

But is there any more standard way of catching a close event beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular-ui's `$close` is actually a standard angular deferred object. You cannot catch a $close event in progress, so actually your second desicion is correct. Use re-defenition of submit button

Comment: Thanks. It seems a pity that the standard behaviour doesn't handle the usual use case. Ah, well, something for Ang2 or Web Components.